# How to do `omz update` as part of my bash script?

Tags: bash, oh-my-zsh

I'm writing a bash script to update oh-my-zsh & plugins. file: `update_omz_plugin.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
ZPLUGINDIR=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins
ZTHEMEDIR=$HOME/.oh-my-zsh/custom/themes

if cd $ZPLUGINDIR/fast-syntax-highlighting; then git pull; else git clone https://github.com/zdharma-continuum/fast-syntax-highlighting.git $ZPLUGINDIR/fast-syntax-highlighting; fi

if cd $ZTHEMEDIR/powerlevel10k; then git pull; else git clone https://github.com/romkatv/powerlevel10k.git $ZTHEMEDIR/powerlevel10k; fi

omz update
```

However, if I do `bash update_omz_plugin.sh`, I got

```
update_omz_plugin.sh: line 9: omz: command not found
```

I thought this is because `omz` is a function defined in `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`? How can I update my script to solve this issue, i.e., make `omz update` work?

Comment: How and why do you expect Bash to know anything at all about your Zsh configuration? Probably something like `zsh -ic "omz update"`

Comment: @tripleee Thanks! `zsh -ic "omz update"` works!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ran into this question when looking for why my script that updated omz was resetting and executing twice.
For whomever it may help, the (current) OMZ FAQ has a section just for this: [how-do-i-manually-update-oh-my-zsh-from-a-script](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-manually-update-oh-my-zsh-from-a-script):

> The best way to do that is to call the `upgrade.sh` script directly. If
> `$ZSH` is defined (it should point to where OMZ is installed), then you
> can call it like so:
>
> ```
> "$ZSH/tools/upgrade.sh"
> ```
>
> The `omz update` command ... restarts the zsh session (which might cause a restart loop).

Of course, in order to have `$ZSH` set you should be running in a zsh script as per [the accepted answer by Robby Russel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72926076/8238184); Although I suppose you could manually resolve it to `/Users/my-user/.oh-my-zsh` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to switch the first line of your script to:

```
#!/bin/zsh
```

The `omz` function is built into Oh My Zsh, which will not be loaded by `/bin/bash`.

Then run `zsh update_omz_plugin.sh`